# Self organizing applications

Tags: c#, architecture, p2p

I have the following requirements for an application that many people will be using in the office - no Server component.  All instances of client apps should somehow negotiate between themselves to decide which client will take on the server role.  And the clients should communicate between themselves via IP.

If and when the client app goes down, another client must take over in a seamless manner.  I understand that having a server would be much, much simpler.  But because the app must be very resilient, the powers that be do not want to risk server going down (or even its backup) and rather rely on this hybrid mesh connectivity, where the server role hops from client to client.

I think I got the app connectivity down.  Basically, when the app starts, it announces itself via UDP (either to a predefined IP address that everything listens to or via UDP broadcast).  From there on, the communication proceeds in a similar manner.

The part I am having problems with is how to negotiate/self-organize between the clients to pick one with a server role.  And how to reliably detect that a client has gone down and then a new negotiation must take place.  The final difficulty is replicating data that's been accumulated by the client with a server role.

I created a prototype in c# that communicates and tries to replicate data, but the negotiation part (particularly coupled with an client failure).

Initially I thought that's what ZeroConf (aka Bonjour) did.  But that just announces available network services.

Anyway, I do not want to reinvent and I can't be the first person to want to do this.  So my questions:

- Is there a pattern that already implements what I described above?
- If so, is there an available .NET (or even native) library for this?
- What are good ways to negotiate server role among the clients?

Comment: Have you seen System.Net.PeerToPeer? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.peertopeer.aspx

Comment: @ChrisShain That might be something.  Had no idea, it existed.  Thanks.

Comment: Sure.  Also see my answer below regarding leader election.  That's a tough problem.

Comment: @ChrisShain recommended zookeeper and I second that. Even though the server is java, there is a .NET  client which works pretty well and is making its way into the distribution, so should be well supported. It does violate the no server component requirement in a way, but a centralized coordination service which is highly resilient is similar to DNS and may be acceptable to the powers that be.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So, you currently have a system in which each client on a LAN will announce itself via UDP to the rest of the LAN. One of the client apps is a "server" and has some additional command & control powers on top of being a client in itself.

This is not a new idea, to be sure. What you want is to add some additional talking during the initial "here I am" connection communication. When a new client yells "here I am" to the rest of the LAN, if there is a server, the server should say "Welcome, I'm the server", and the new client app now knows which client is acting as the server. All other clients should probably say "hi" as well. If there isn't a server, the new client should first repeat the "hello" (it is UDP after all; you have to expect some messages not to be received), and if nobody responds, this new client is the only one on the network and is the "server" by default. If there are others but none are claiming to be the server, the clients can "discuss amongst themselves" to determine a new server.

In addition to this, the server copy should periodically (maybe every 3-5 seconds) yell out "I'm still here" to everyone; this is known as a "heartbeat" message and is a very common alternative to the two-way "ping" method of verification.

If the server app (or any copy, really) closes normally, it should yell out "goodbye everyone, figure out who's the next server". The remaining clients can then discuss amongst themselves. If the client acting as server crashes, the clients will miss the server's "heartbeat" message, ask "who's the server", and if nobody still responds the clients will discuss amongst themselves.

Now, clients "discussing amongst themselves" can be as simple or as complex as you like. The simplest would be for whichever client says "OK, I'm server now" to become server. You would probably have to include some sort of time in the message so that if another computer says it at the same time the clients can say "well client 15 said it first so we're going with him". Clients can "vote"; have each client talk to all others to determine nominal latency between that client and all others, and that client will "vote" for the lowest-latency connection (no client may vote for itself unless it discovers it's the only one). Most votes wins.

Or, a server can, as part of its "heartbeat" message, say "if I go down, my successor is client X"; and if a heartbeat is missed and the subsequent "are you still there, server" messages from the clients are not responded to, the clients can say "the king is dead! Long live King Client X!".

Understand that by necessity, this layer of governance within an all-client system in picking an "authoritative" client to become the server is going to dramatically increase the complexity of client communications. Also, while your use of the UDP protocol lends itself to speedy communication, UDP messages collide ALL THE TIME; if you're talking while another person is talking, your messages collide. So, I would recommend the use of TCP instead of UDP for most communication in this software in which it is necessary for a particular client to be heard. That is any direct interrogation of a client ("are you still there, server?"), whatever process you use to have the clients decide who a new server is, etc etc.

Comment: What do you mean by `UDP messages collide ALL THE TIME`?  Meaning, they don't arrive at their destination?  I've been doing UDP for a long time and have yet to see it.  Is there a specific condition that causes the "collision".

Comment: Predetermining a successor can help mitigate the loss of data in the event of a server crash. Have the successor host a copy of the data being used, and send updates every so often from the real server. If the server crashes, everything up to the last update is still available. If the successor crashes, appoint a new successor and dump the data to it.

Comment: @AngryHacker; I meant that UDP is, by its design, prone to collisions; the protocol does not have the error-checking and other data-integrity measures that TCP/IP does. It's good for telemetry and other types of data feeds that can tolerate a lost message or two; it's not very good for messages that must be received by the other party in their entirety no matter what else they're sending out or listening to.

Comment: As the determining of a new "authoritative" server requires the final decision to be very clearly communicated, I'm simply recommending TCP instead of UDP for at least certain communications, as the protocol itself will help ensure that the message is received as intended by ALL parties, so there isn't a situation where multiple computers assert themselves as the "server" because neither of them heard the other and so both think there's no other "contender".

Comment: @KeithS is right, but doesn't take it far enough. There are numerous ways that even with TCP your system can "Accidentally" elect multiple servers.  Imagine that you have a network with the following topology (Clients 1,2,3) -> (Switch 1) -> (Switch 2) <- (Switch 3) <- (Clients 3,4,5).  What happens when Client 1 is the server and (Switch 2) gets turned off?  In a system that doesn't use an algorithmically correct leader election protocol, one of Clients 3,4,5) will be elected, and then you have 2 servers.  Oops.

Comment: If Switch 2 gets turned off, then you now have two LANs that can't see each other. The clients on the severed network branch must then elect their own leader. Now, if Switch 2 gets turned back on again, the two servers will hear each others' "heartbeats", say "waitamminnit, I'M the server", and should hash it out between them from there (Client 1 should probably win the comparison as it is the longer-running of the two, assuming it never crashed while the switch was down).

Comment: Yes, assuming having 2 servers is OK during the network partition, that's fine.  In the vast majority of cases where something like this is being done, that's not an acceptable situation because of the potential for integrity violations (mostly in situations where the current server's view of the world is *the* authority, and therefore having two servers could lead to unresolvable conflicts as to the state of the world).

Comment: @KeithS: UDP does have error checking. There is a checksum in the header: http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc768.txt Also UDP is no more prone to collision than anything sent over a physical layer. Both TCP and UDP packets can get lost for a variety of reasons, the difference is that TCP will resend a lost packet, UDP is designed to 'Fire and Forget'. You can in fact build TCP on top of UDP if you wanted to. I wouldn't recommend it though.

Answer (score 6):

Selection of a server amongst a group of machines, whether those machines are also clients or not, is an extremely nontrivial problem.  It's called leader election.  The seminal work that you should be reading is Leslie Lamport's [The Part Time Parliament](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/people/lamport/pubs/lamport-paxos.pdf), which describes the Paxos protocol.  Paxos has been leveraged by Google to develop a system called [Chubby](http://research.google.com/archive/chubby-osdi06.pdf), which serves the purpose that you describe.

That said, you should probably look at a system like [Apache ZooKeeper](http://zookeeper.apache.org/), which is an open-source (albeit Java) implementation of a distributed leader election, and more broadly, distributed lock management which has been thoroughly tested under massive load.  The [Hadoop](http://hadoop.apache.org) distributed data storage and computing platform, and specifically [HBase](http://hbase.apache.org), a distributed database that runs on Hadoop, make heavy use of ZooKeeper to decide "who is in charge" amongst a group of servers.  This way any of them can go down, and the others decide amongst themselves about who takes over the job.

As I mentioned earlier, leader election is fraught with error.  It's very hard to get right.  I've implemented paxos "for fun" a half-dozen times in C# and *all* of my implementations have bugs in them.

Answer (score 3):

Why do you need to negotiate the role of server at all? Think about this for a second. If each "client" can handle the "server" duties for work initiated at the client, then all handle both client and server, to an extent. Then the only issue is negotiating replication of the persisted state between clients and handling concurrency when two clients are handling the same bit of state (the hardest part, from my perspective, would be alerting other clients state has been changed when one client "saves" the data and having other clients working on the state open up a method to resolve clashes -- may not be an issue if last in always wins, but that is rare).

If you are truly going to mesh, then each client should be able to handle it's on work independently of the others and only communicate changes to persisted state so the copies match.

the above assumes that the number of times more than one person uses the same state at the same time is limited. If that is the normal scenario, then you will have to figure out some of your "server" logic.

Comment: > Why do you need to negotiate the role of server at all?

Because only one client can have access to a precious resource that is needed by all.